# React native AppState "change" event not triggered by Android 12 Task Manager

Tags: react-native, events, taskmanager, android-12

Our react-native 0.66 Android app has an AppState `change` handler which is called when the app goes into the background / foreground...

```js
    import {AppState} from 'react-native';

    ...

    this.changeUnsubscribe = AppState.addEventListener('change', this.handleChange)

    ...

    handleChange(nextAppState) { console.log(`App state changed to: ${nextAppState}`) }
```

Works perfectly on Android 10. However on Android 12, the change event isn't happening when the user brings up the Task Manager.

Instead the event happens when you swipe up the app in the Task Manager (to close the app).

Unfortunately that causes a problem: It seems Android 12 limits the amount of activity you can perform as the app is closing. We're trying to save user data when the app goes into the background, and it's not always managing it. Pre-Android 12 our app managed it fine.

I can't find any mention of this new behaviour in the react-native or Android docs. Any tips anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question, hope it helps others:

For react-native v0.66 on Android 12 (may be the case for other versions): The system Task Manager no longer triggers the AppState `change` event.

It now triggers an AppState `blur` event. Returning to the app triggers a `focus` event. The AppState `currentState` will continue to be `active` while Task Manager is in the foreground.

Comment: can you please provide a source for this? I could not find any article stating the same.

Comment: @Specter123 I just discovered it on my own, but https://reactnative.dev/docs/appstate#blur-android gives an example of: "[...] when the user pulls down the notification drawer. AppState won't change but the blur event will get fired". The same goes for the task manager / multitasking view / app switcher / app overview or whatever the hell it's called these days.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

I hope they add it in the docs soon. It worked fine, just the problem is there are unnecessary updates that need to be made due to not-so-distinguished blur and background in Android 13+. Even when a modal pops up inside the app, the appstate is set to be blurred.